# How to automatically reload Django when files change?

Tags: python, django, web-applications, livereload

How to automatically monitor .py, .js and other source code files to restart a Django (or any other for that matter) application and refresh the browser when the source changes? This is possible in Rails using guard, in JS apps using grunt-contrib-watch and the accompanying livereload browser plugin. How can I do it for Python web apps such as Django?

I start my Django server with

```
foreman start
```

this is my Procfile:

```
web: newrelic-admin run-program gunicorn app.wsgi
```

as suggested by the Heroku/Newrelic docs or the usual

```
python manage.py runserver
```

The `runserver` method does restart the server on .py source changes, but not the browser and doesn't watch other files - I could run guard alongside it, but then I have two processes I have to take care of, whereas grunt or rake offer unified interfaces. I'm wondering what is the recommended way of doing this among Python developers?

I could not find any detailed, comprehensive documentation on this - only incomplete discussions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12773763/gunicorn-autoreload-on-source-change) and [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19073878/how-to-livereload-django-templates).

Comment: To achieve parity with gunicorn / runserver reloading, use the --reload flag in your Procfile. I don't have a good answer for the browser reload, unfortunately.

Comment: Adam Johnson has just released a modern Django package for it. https://pypi.org/project/django-browser-reload/

Comment: Working with others' projects just open `/root/.bash_history` and look for `sudo systemctl restart gunicorn` or similar.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You don't need a browser extension to accomplish auto refreshes.  Take a look at https://github.com/tjwalch/django-livereload-server.

I posted a more extensive answer about this at https://stackoverflow.com/a/36961244/2950621

It works by using a manage.py command (server) to monitor your .js and other static files.  The server sends a signal to the browser via websockets.  There is some client-side code injected on every page.  The injected code responds to the signal and refresh the browser.

Comment: Thanks works fine, when using incognito window.

Answer (score 19):

Install this django app:

```
pip install django-livesync
```

On your django settings file add something like:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    '...',
    'livesync',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    '...',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'livesync.core.middleware.DjangoLiveSyncMiddleware',
)
```

**Beware to register 'livesync' before 'django.contrib.staticfiles' if you are using it.**

Now, just start your development server:

```
python manage.py runserver
```

Check this out for more details: https://github.com/fabiogibson/django-livesync

Comment: I realize your repo and this answer are four years old, but just using your instructions my Firefox (ver. 94) won't reload the DJango templates. Is more configuration needed in 2021?

Comment: Not working, probably outdated. Not sure tho, I just tried and it didn't worked for me

Answer (score 7):

Using `python manage.py runserver` is what most use. You'll have to use another tool like: http://livejs.com/ to refresh the browser itself since Django really isn't aware of it.

Answer (score 5):

Frustrated with all the explicit refreshes, I created a browser extension, for both Firefox and Chrome, to automate this. The extension works with a Django app that you add to your app list in INSTALLED_APPS. You can find out more at the  [github repo](https://github.com/harikvpy/django-autorefresh).

Though the repo has entire source code, the extensions are also available in the respective web store. Just search for 'Django Auto Refresh'. With these, you just need to copy the app into our project's folder and include it via INSTALLED_APPS. I wanted to add a pip setup script, but haven't found the time to do it.

HTH. Apologies if this sounds like self promotion.

Answer (score 1):

I tried several answers here. But the browser did not seem to show the recent changes of the code. It worked for me when I opened Chrome in ***Incognito Mode***.

Comment: This sounds more like a caching issue, especially if the code changes were CSS or JS. `Ctrl+F5` to hard refresh a page, or in Chrome, enable the option to never cache when dev tools are open.