# Django - How to update a list of models on a page instantly without refreshing?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, django, django-models

In my html I use a bootstrap list group and I use a for loop to loop through all instances of a model and display a list item with the name of the instance. On the same page, I have buttons to create, edit, and delete instances. All those buttons do their actions using ajax post requests, so no page loading is required there, but after clicking a button, I have to refresh the page to see the changes in the list. Do I need to do another ajax request to make it refresh automatically?

html file

```
<ul class="list-group" id="instance_list">
    {% for instance in instance_names %}
    <li class="list-group-item">
        <input class="form-check-input" name="instance_name" type="checkbox" value="{{instance}}" aria-label="...">{{instance}}
    </li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
<button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" id="create">Create</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="edit">Edit</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" id="delete">Delete</button>
```

Comment: You might need to  manually add the new entry to your list

Comment: Show here maybe that can help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19094720/how-to-automatically-reload-django-when-files-change/36968756

Comment: @Amir That question is about automatically refreshing the browser when source code files change. I don't think that's related to my question at all.