# Django automatically reload page files changes not working with django-livesync, how to solved the issue?

Tags: django, templates

I have shown many posts in StackOverflow that those developer using "django-livesync" module to reload the pages and I tried same way but it's not reloading when I change any files.

I followed,
https://github.com/fabiogibson/django-livesync
and
[How to automatically reload Django when files change?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19094720/how-to-automatically-reload-django-when-files-change/19123657)
those techniques are failed that's why posting it again because I didn't see any solution anymore.

I tried,

*1st*

pip install django-livesync

*2nd*

added "livesync" in INSTALLED_APPS before 'django.contrib.staticfiles'

*3rd*

added middleware

'livesync.core.middleware.DjangoLiveSyncMiddleware',

finally

`python manage.py runserver`

the server is running but reloading not working.
Whenever I change any templates files, views, etc page not reloading automatically.
below the project structure,

[image]

and requirements.txt files for each version

[image]

my goal is to reload the Django server http://127.0.0.1:8000/ automatically whenever I do python manage.py runserver.
I will be very appreciated if get a good answer,
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Finally Solved by adding this to settings.py file:

```
DJANGO_LIVESYNC = {
    'PORT': 8080,
    'HOST': '127.0.0.1'
}
```

For the Port value use whatever you are using while starting/running the server.
For default usage go for 8000.

Comment: Still doesn't work for me using PORT 8000.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably a bit late. But I had a similar problem and managed to solve it by adding

```
DJANGO-LIVESYNC = {
    'PORT': 8000
}
```

to the settings file. The default isn't 8000.

Comment: thanks for comment but it's not working even I try all tutorial but still page not reloading.