# How to make docker container changes to reflect in the local machine?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-container

I have created an app using Django, Python3, and Docker on Windows. The app is working perfectly fine and producing the expected results. My Problem here is that my application will produce certain files as a result and it will be stored in a folder. After dockerizing when running the app it produces the output files in the container but it is not reflecting the changes in my local machine. Then I tried to **Bind mounts** in the **volumes** in the docker-compose.yml file. Even after that changes don't seem reflected in the local machine.

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM python:3.7.6-slim

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

WORKDIR /app

COPY . /app

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

EXPOSE 8003
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3.2.22'

services:
  analyzer:
    build:
      context: ./analyser
    command: bash -c "python ./analyser/manage.py migrate && python ./analyser/manage.py runserver 8003"
    volumes:
      - ./analyser:/app/analyser
    ports:
      - "8003:8003"
    restart: always
```

I don't understand why it is not reflecting the changes. If the changes in the local are updated in the container means the changes in the container should be reflected in the local changes right? Then I checked whether it was related to a permissions issue because my application is on a local disk:c. So I tried giving 'RW' the user permission to make changes in the local folder and even tried running docker as an administrator. But both ways doesn't worked out.

**Docker UI Inspect results**

```
"Mounts": [
        {
            "Type": "bind",
            "Source": "C:\\Users\\Version_1\\analyser",
            "Destination": "/app/analyser",
            "Mode": "rw",
            "RW": true,
            "Propagation": "rprivate"
        }
    ],
    "Config": {
        "Hostname": "63f89a09df2d",
        "Domainname": "",
        "User": "",
        "AttachStdin": false,
        "AttachStdout": true,
        "AttachStderr": true,
        "ExposedPorts": {
            "8003/tcp": {}
        },
```

I would like to get some suggestions or ideas to overcome this issue. Thank you so much in advance :).

Comment: How did you checked is not changing? I guess the issue is missing `hot reload` look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19094720/how-to-automatically-reload-django-when-files-change

Comment: It looks like your Dockerfile is missing its `CMD`, and it looks like you might be bind-mounting a host directory over the image directory that contains the application's code.  Did you mean to bind-mount a directory over the data directory instead?  Where are the data files actually stored?

Comment: @zori Thank you for the suggestion. I am not sure about this **Hot reload**. But I think my case is a little different. I have found that the files are changing while checking the files section in the docker container it has shown that the file was modified.  But when I check the folder in my local machine it still has old results.

Comment: @DavidMaze In the Dockerfile, while creating the image, I am copying the entire folder from my local. It has the output folder inside it. Which stores the final results.  After running with docker the file in that output folder in the docker image is modified but those modified files are not reflected in my local.

Comment: One idea is to try using `bind` instead of `volume` and use `propagation` set to `shared`, in your case is `rprivate` as it's for volumes more about it [here](https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/#configure-bind-propagation)

Comment: Which container directory is the output directory?  Can you [edit] the question to (briefly) show the code that's writing there?

Comment: @zori Thank you so much :). This idea worked and now the modified files are reflected in the local.